# TypeError: command.execute is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this is the error I get repeatedly please help!
TypeError: command.execute is not a function

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online!');
    client.user.setActivity('~help | Aishiteimasu!', {type: 'PLAYING'});
});


client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)

        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
    return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
}


    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `Insufficient arguments provided!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }
    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
        console.log(command)
    }
})
client.login(token);
```

and the relevant command that it doesnt work on

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
    module.exports = {
      name: "ping",
      description: "Pong!",
      cooldown: 5,
      aliases: [ "latency", "uptime" ],
}
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
                message.channel.send("Pinging") .then(m => {
                    const ping = m.createdTimestamp - createdTimestamp
                    const choices = ["H-How was it?", "P-Please be good...", "I-I hope it isn't bad!"]
                    const response = choices[Math.floor(math.Random() * choices.length)]

                    m.edit(`${response}: Bot Latency: ${ping}, API Latency: ${Math.round(bot.ping)}`)
                });
            }
```

it works on all my othercommands, which are synchronous but it seems to break when i tried an async code. I also don't understand what the error means, let alone fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple commands with the same file name or `module.export.name`?

Comment: nope, from what i double checked, there are no duplicates in the file names/commands
do i have to include `module.export.name` in my ping.js file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you are supposed to be using `module.exports.execute = async (bot, message, args) => {` instead of `module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {`, as you are trying to use a execute function when it doesnt exist.

Comment: so the `command.execute` in index.js and the `command.execute` in ping.js should be the same?

Comment: Yes, I see it now, you didn't pass `bot` through as a parameter then attempted to use it in the command, that's why you are running into that error